# Silent exception when executing script with IActiveScript

Tags: com, iactivescript

I'm using a com object from jscript.dll
IActiveScriptSite is implemented, so when there is an error, OnScriptError is triggerd.
That works fine, but on some desktops, the error is not triggered, the script just stops executing when the error occurs.
I guess there's a setting on windows, maybe on iexplore, but i just can't find it.

Comment: Have you checked in Internet Explorer's Tools/Options/Advanced and in the Browsing settings, you have "disable script debugging" for IE and others, and "display a notification about every script error"

Comment: I tried every combo of these settings, but i cannot reproduce the silent problem that happens on some customers desktops